# How to simplify $(1-2^{n-1})t^n+(3-2^{n-1})t^{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}2{n-1 \choose k}t^{n-k-1}$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, polynomials

Let $$h(n,t)=(1-2^{n-1})t^n+(3-2^{n-1})t^{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}2{n-1 \choose k}t^{n-k-1}.$$ 
Then $h(n,1)=0$. Therefore $(1-t)$ is a factor of $h(n,t)$. How to write $h(n,t)$ as $(1-t)g(n)$ for some $g(n)$? Thank you very much.

I am trying to simplify $h(n,t)$ as follows. 
$$h(n,t)=(1-2^{n-1})t^n+(3-2^{n-1})t^{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}2{n-1 \choose k}t^{n-k-1} \\
= (1-2^{n-1})t^n+(3-2^{n-1})t^{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2{n-1 \choose k}t^{n-k-1} - 2t^{n-1}-2 \\
= (1-2^{n-1})t^n+(3-2^{n-1})t^{n-1}+2(1+t)^{n-1} - 2t^{n-1}-2 \\
= (1-2^{n-1})(t^n+t^{n-1}) + 2(1+t)^{n-1} - 2.
$$

Comment: Note that we have $2^{n-1}-1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}$. In this way you could find $g(n,t)$.

Comment: @Nirvanacs, thank you very much for your suggestions.